# How do I refer to a windows form control by name (C# / VB)

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

Suppose I have a label control on a windows form called "UserName". How can I refer to that label programmatically using the label name?

For example I can do:

```
For each ctrl as Control in TabPage.Controls
If ctrl.Name = "UserName" Then
' Do something
End If
Next
```

This seems quite inefficient. I would like to do something like:

```
TabPage.Controls("UserName").Text = "Something"
```

I did some googling but couldn't find a satisfactory answer. Most suggested looping, some said .NET 2005 doesn't support direct refenece using string name, and FindControl method was asp.net only...

**EDIT**

Thanks for the response so far. Here is a bit more detail.

I have a windows form with three tabpages, all of which a very similar in design and function i.e. same drop down menus, labels, react in simlar way to events etc.

Rather than write code for each event per tabpage I have built a class that controls the events etc. per tabpage.

For example, on each tabpage there is a Label called "RecordCounter" that simply shows the number of rows in the datagridview when it is populated by selection of a variable in a drop down menu.

So what I want to be able to do is, upon selection of a variable in the drop down menu, the datagridview populates itself with data, and then I simply want to display the number of rows in a label ("RecordCounter").

This is exactly the same process on each tabpage so what I am doing is passing the tabpage to the class and then I want to be able to refer to the "RecordCounter" and then update it.

In my class I set the ActivePage property to be the TabPage that the user has selected and then want to be able to do something like:

```
ActivePage.RecordCounter.Text = GetNumberOfRows()
```

Answer (score 10):

You should be able to use `Find()`:

```
TabPage.Controls.Find("UserName", false);
```

This will search all of the child controls and return an array of those that match the string. If you specify `true` for the 2nd argument, it will look through the controls of the child controls as well.

Comment: +1, I was just typing my own answer. Here's a link to the MSDN docs on Find http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find.aspx

Answer (score 8):

Is your control added at design time or runtime?

If it is added at design time then you can simply reference it by name: Me.UserName.Text = "Something"

If it is added at runtime you can use the following:

```
TabPage.Controls.Find("UserName", true)
```

The second parameter tells it to search all children as well, so this should definitely find your control.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the question context, I think you're making it too difficult.  in code, you just use thelabel name as your reference as in:

```
UserName.Text = "Something"
```

Is there something you're trying to accomplish that makes that not right?

Answer (score 2):

How are you creating your controls?

If it's at design time, then each control should have a named reference.

If you're adding controls at run time, then you could create a dictionary to contain references indexed by string and add each control to that dictionary when it's created.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to pass the controls to the class in addition to or instead of the tabpage. For example, you could have a RecordCounter property in addition to your ActivePage property. (Incidentally, Find is efficient to code but not so efficient at runtime.)

Answer (score 0):

TabPage.Controls.Find("UserName", true) works for me. But i need to assign it to controls[] class and next i am assigning it to textbox like controls.