# VB.net Duplicate textbox inputs validation

Tags: vb.net, validation, numbers, duplicates

I need help with one function in VB.net.

I have 6 textboxes limited only to numbers and only to numbers from 1-25 which user must fill in. I need a way to check for duplicate numbers in textboxes when i click button.

Here is my code so far:

```
Private Sub validate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles validate.Click
    For Each t In textBoxes
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(t.Text) Then
            nr1.Text = ""
            nr2.Text = ""
            nr3.Text = ""
            nr4.Text = ""
            nr5.Text = ""
            nr6.Text = ""
            nr1.Focus()
            Exit Sub
            Exit For
        End If
    Next t

    Dim rand = GetRandom(1, 1715)
    Dim miliseconds = CLng(DateTime.Now.Subtract(New DateTime(1970, 1, 1)).TotalMilliseconds)

    strSQL = xxxxxxxx

    Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(strSQL, CONNECTION)
    da.Fill(ds)
    nr1.Text = ""
    nr2.Text = ""
    nr3.Text = ""
    nr4.Text = ""
    nr5.Text = ""
    nr6.Text = ""
    value.Text = "1"
    broj1.Focus()

    list()
End Sub
```

Thank you :)

Ok, i managed to get it working, here is the code:

Ok, thank you guys for answering me.

I have found solution and if anyone needs it i will post it here:

```
Dim textBoxes As TextBox() = New TextBox() {nr1, nr2, nr3, nr4, nr5, nr6}
For i As Integer = 0 To textBoxes.Length - 2
    For j As Integer = i + 1 To textBoxes.Length - 1
        If textBoxes(i).Text = textBoxes(j).Text Then
            //failed to execute, found duplicates
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Duplicate value.")
            textBoxes(j).Focus()
            Return
        End If
    Next
Next
//sucessful
```

Comment: Where are you checking for coincidence between your textboxes?  What are you trying to achieve here?  Are you trying to keep the user from entering a duplicate value in any of the textboxes?

Comment: Yes, i need to check if user inputs duplicate value in any of textboxes. If there are duplicate values i need to pop messagebox and warn them.

Answer (score -1):

Well if there is some duplicate, it means that there are at least 2.

You have to do something like this

```
for(int i=1; i<6; i++)
for(int j=i+1; j<=6; j++)
{
 if(the value of the control with the name nr+i has the same value as the control with the name nr+j)
{
// there is a duplicate
}
}
```

To get a control by name in VB - [How do I refer to a windows form control by name (C# / VB)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1178967/how-do-i-refer-to-a-windows-form-control-by-name-c-vb)

I hope you can translate this in VB.

Comment: He asked for VB.net, you should answer in VB.net