# Several NumericUpDown looking for duplicate

Tags: vb.net, loops, numericupdown

I'm a newbie VB.NET programmer. I'm currently trying to figure out a simple Window Form Application for a Volleyball match. I've created 14 Textboxes (for names) and NumericUpDown (for player numbers).
Now, when I press TeamHome_VerifyButton I would like to check if any of NumericUpDown values from TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value to TeamHome_PlayerNumber14.Value duplicate. Of course, I did it with multiple IF's, but this code is just... strange, big, messy... just BAD. It works, but it isn't the way I should write it. But I don't have idea how to do it. I can't just do something like TeamHome_PlayerNumber+counter.ToString.Value where counter would be increased by loop.

```
If TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber4.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber5.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber6.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber7.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber8.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber9.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber10.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber11.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber12.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber13.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber1.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber14.Value Then
        MessageBox.Show("Numer zawodnika 1 się powtarza!", "Powtórzenie!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    ElseIf TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber4.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber5.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber6.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber7.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber8.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber9.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber10.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber11.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber12.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber13.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber2.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber14.Value Then
        MessageBox.Show("Numer zawodnika 2 się powtarza!", "Powtórzenie!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    ElseIf TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber4.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber5.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber6.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber7.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber8.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber9.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber10.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber11.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber12.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber13.Value Or TeamHome_PlayerNumber3.Value = TeamHome_PlayerNumber14.Value Then
        MessageBox.Show("Numer zawodnika 3 się powtarza!", "Powtórzenie!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
  'And like this to TeamHome_PlayerNumber14.Value
End If
```

Any ideas? Probably solution is veery easy, but I can't manage it to work. Found out several codes, tried to rebuild it, just doens't work.
Thank you in advance :)

PS: These "Numer zawodnika X się powtarza" (The number of player X is duplicated) isn't necessary, just a MessageBox with an error would be fine. It's not important to be so much specified which player numbers duplicate.

Comment: A different approach would be to change the legal selections as each thing is picked.  that would prevent dupes rather than just detect them

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim NumUpDown As NumericUpDown() = New NumericUpDown() {TeamHome_PlayerNumber1, TeamHome_PlayerNumber2, TeamHome_PlayerNumber3, TeamHome_PlayerNumber4, TeamHome_PlayerNumber5}
For i As Integer = 0 To NumUpDown.Length - 2
    For j As Integer = i + 1 To NumUpDown.Length - 1
        If NumUpDown(i).Value = NumUpDown(j).Value Then
            MessageBox.Show(Me, "Duplicate value.")
            Return
        End If
    Next
Next
```

[Just changed this answer from TextBox to NumericUpDown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20914666/vb-net-duplicate-textbox-inputs-validation)